# How to drop a schema forcefully?

Tags: azure, data-warehouse

How to drop a schema forcefully so that all of its dependencies are gone in SQL Datawarehouse? cascade function is not available in datawarehouse, is there anyway to delete, a schema and its dependencies forcefully?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself by using the below statement:-

```
while(exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             where TABLE_NAME != '__MigrationHistory' 
             AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'))
begin
 declare @sql nvarchar(2000)
 SELECT TOP 1 @sql=('DROP TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME
 + ']')
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_NAME != '__MigrationHistory' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
exec (@sql)
 PRINT @sql
end
GO
```

This will drop all the schema and dependencies that are created. Works well for Azure DataWarehouse.

Comment: That won't allow for views, stored procedures, etc. that may be created in the schema. Use the same approach, but think about using sys.views, sys.tables, sys.procedures, sys.functions, etc. to drive each block.

Comment: But TSQL Azure Datawarehouse doesn't support views and procedure

Comment: I guarantee you that both views and stored procedures are supported on Azure SQL Data Warehouse. We use them. Here's the documentation for sys.views, for example, as I suggested earlier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-views-transact-sql